# a file that was removed in working branch being copied when merging to develop branch

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I have a develop branch which has a few files in app module.

develop branch

```
App Module  
-fileA
-fileB
```

then created a new branch(called featureA branch) and I moved fileB from App Module to Feature Module.

featureA branch

```
App Module
-fileA
Feature Module
-fileB
```

now I am trying to merge featureA branch into develop branch by 3 steps below

1. pulling develop branch into featureA branch
2. pushing featureA branch to github
3. requesting PR that merging featureA branch into develop

Once I am done with step1, fileB is being copied over to featureA branch and now featureA branch looks like this.

featureA branch

```
App Module
-fileA
-fileB
Feature Module
-fileB
```

so I remove fileB from App Module(since it is duplicated) in featureA branch after step1. Then, proceed step2 and step3.
now, github complains about status of featureA branch being outdated and suggests me to update the featureA branch to be updated with an update button.
once I click that button, it will copy that fileB into App Module again.
I am like in the infinite loop as removing that file by myself and duplicating it back in by github.

I think there is a workaround by removing that file with a new branch from develop branch and merging the branch back into develop branch before featureA branch merging into develop branch. but this is not really what I want.

I will appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Have you commit the `App Module/fileA` deletion ? Did you use `git mv` ?

Comment: I did commit the `App Module/fileA` deletion with gitKraken. (not sure if `git mv` has been involved or not)

Comment: can you execute `git status ` and post the outcome in the question to better understand the situation.

Comment: Did you have a conflict on `fileB` when you merged in `develop` in step 1?

Comment: gitKraken didn't say anything about fileB when I merged develop branch into featureA branch in step1

Comment: It's strange that your new commit is deleting `fileB` from the old location, and merging `develop` brings it back without a conflict. Your commit definitely deletes it? (Note a rename or move is actually a deletion and addition of the file in a new path.)